# Using python pandas how can we select very specific rows and associated column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am still learning python, kindly excuse if the question looks trivial to some.

I have a csv file with following format and I want to extract a small segment of it and write to another csv file:
[image]

So, this is what I want to do:

1. Just extract the entries under actor_list2 and the corresponding id column and write it to a csv file in following format.

[image]

Since the format is not a regular column headers followed by some values, I am not sure how to select starting point based on a cell value in a particular column.e.g. even if we consider actor_list2, then it may have any number of entries under that. Please help me understand if it can be done using pandas dataframe processing capability.

Update: The reason why I would like to automate it is because there can be thousands of such files and it would be impractical to manually get that info to create the final csv file which will essentially have a row for each file.

Comment: Can it be automated? Yes. Should it be automated? Not really. I'd rather put effort on getting data in a normally-formatted csv then mocking about with this one.

Comment: Why did you downvote it? A problem is a problem, you may have a different solution proposed but what is the need to downvote?

Comment: I didn't. Someone else did. Not sure why. To me it's a sensible question, but once again, a better solution is getting better data. Automating this would be tedious. When pandas reads a csv, by default it reads the first row as column names... well in your case it will be 'total time', '4426.72' and a bunch of nans. Given how erratic the formatting is, even if you did loads it properly by skipping some rows and setting a specific row and your column names, there's no cure if the next time, there's one additional row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nour-Allah has  pointed out the formatting here is not very regular to say the least. The best you can do if that is the case that your data comes out like this every time is to skip some rows of the file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('blabla.csv', skiprows=list(range(17)), nrows=8)
df_res = df.loc[:, ['actor_list2', 'ID']]
```

This should get you the result but given how erratic formatting is, this is no way to automate. What if next time there's another actor? Or one fewer? Even Nour-Allah's solution would not help there.

Honestly, you should just get better data.

Comment: I have just a proposal method and not a rigid solution. your solution is based on observation too. @pavel

Answer (score 0):

As the `CSV` file you have is not regular, so a lot of empty position, that contains 'nan' objects. Meanwhile, the columns will be indexed.

I will use pandas to read

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("not_regular_format.csv", header=None)
```

Then, initialize and empty dictionary to store the results in, and use it to build an output DataFram, which finally send its content to a `CSV` file

```
target={}
```

Now you need to find `actor_list2` in the second columns which is the column with the index `0`, and if it exists, start store the names and scores from in the next rows and columns `1` and `2` in the dictionary `target`

```
rows_index = df[df[1] == 'actor_list2'].index
if len(rows_index) > 0:
    i = rows_index[0]
    while True:
        i += 1
        name = df.iloc[i, 1]
        score = df.iloc[i, 2]
        if pd.isna(name): # the names sequence is finished and 'nan' object exists.
            break
        target[name] = [score]
```

and finally, construct DataFrame and write the new `output.csv` file

```
df_output=pd.DataFrame(target)
df_output.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Now, you can go anywhere with the given example above.

Good Luck